# O que é request.post e qual sua função?

Tags: python-3.x

Estou estudando python e me deparei com tal metódo, mas mesmo lendo a documentação ainda não compreendi.
Desde já, agradeço.
[A documentação do python que estava lendo](http://docs.python-requests.org/pt_BR/latest/user/quickstart.html)

Comment: Qual função? O modulo/biblioteca serve para fazer requisições http, como o curl por ex... https://medium.com/clebertech/como-funciona-uma-requisi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-http-cf76f66fe36e

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Através de request.post você envia informações para um endpoint para serem processadas e te retornar um response.

Exemplo:

```
import requests

API_ENDPOINT = "http://teste.com/api/api_post"

data = {'code':'python'}

r = requests.post(url = API_ENDPOINT, data = data)
```

Em r terei a resposta dessa requisição.